# Не понимаю почему не изменяется ссылка в коллекции

Tags: java

Есть код:

```
 public List<Contact> findByALL() throws SQLException {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    try(Connection connection = DaoFactory.getConnection()) {
        PreparedStatement ps= connection.prepareStatement("select * from contact");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Contact contact;
        while (rs.next()){
            contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            contact.setFirst_name(rs.getString("first_name"));
            contact.setLast_name(rs.getString("last_name"));

            list.add(contact);

        }
    }
```

В последней строке, мы кладем сcылку на объект,в коллекцию.
Далее идем в первую строку цикла и присваиваем ссылке новый объект и снова его ложим в лист.
Если ссылка именованный блок памяти указывающий на обьект, то почему листе находятся ссылки на два разных объекта, а не на один и тот же? По моему разумению, второй проход цикла должен перезаписать contact находящийся в листе.

Comment: Потому что оператор `new` создает новый объект. Не важно как вы назвали переменную (ссылку), за пределами итерации она уже ничего не знает о предыдущем значении. Если в переделах одной итерации опять вызвать `contact = new Contact();`, то это будет уже совсем другой объект. И ссылаться поле `contact`будет уже на новый объект.

Comment: То есть в лист мы уже записали адрес объекта, а не адрес ячейки где лежит указатель(ссылка) на объект?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы передаёте листу значение переменной, а не саму переменную. В переменной лежит ссылка на объект и каждый раз когда применяют new значение переменной меняется

Comment: Так вот в переменной ссылочного типа лежит адрес на кучу с объектом

Comment: Вот я этот момент и не понимаю. В значении переменной лежит ссылка на новый объект Contact, к примеру объект №1.
Мы этот именованый блок памяти ссылкой записали в List. Затем создали объект №2 и в этот же именованный блок памяти записали другую ссылку на другой объект. Получается что в листе ссылка тоже должна начать указывать на обьект 2 вместо объекта 1.

Comment: Давайте объясню проще. Var object = address1; в переменной лежит адрес 1; передаём листу address1  а не адрес object в этом вся и разница. Когда вы присваиваете новый адрес то в переменной лежит он но при этом адреса переменной не меняется

Comment: Азис спасибо !!!

Comment: Не за что. Рад помочь